# Calculate the accuracy of the multi-stage state machine

Tags: probability

This is an application question. I have a state machine with 2 stages.

1. The first stage alone of the machine has the accuracy of 90%.

2.If the first stage output is 1, then goes to 2-1 of second stage. The 2-1 of the second stage alone has the accuracy of 70%.

3.If the first stage output is 0, then goes to 2-2 of the second stage. The 2-2 of the second stage alone has the accuracy of 20%.

I may introduce multiple stages (>2 stages)soon.

May I know the formula to calculate the overall accuracy of the multi-stage state machine ?

Comment: This is a **Markov chain** and there are effficient methods to calculate these probabilities.

Comment: @sascha, The probability of making state transistion is unknown now. Only accuracy at each state is reported.

Comment: Then define it more formally. I'm not sure what you exactly defined. Maybe the viterbi algorithm might come into play.